# Output values between ' and a ,

Tags: php, string, syntax

I need a special form style of values written. From (my write function of mysql query data fields), I need these values between '(clip) and ,(comma) to seperate them for reading them for a geocode location.

```
 fwrite($file, $tier['latitude'].','.$tier['longitude']."\r\n");
```

To this result (attention to the commas and clips):

'value1' , 'value2'

but I can't get it, instead I always get a syntax error.

Thank you very much for someone who can give me a hint

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please edit your question and try to clarify a little what you're expecting to achieve? It's unclear at the moment.

Comment: What does the error say.....?

Comment: the error says in different  tryouts syntax error unexpected t_variable for example if i write this (attention to  surrounded clips)
 fwrite($file, '$tier['latitude']'.','.'$tier['longitude']'

Comment: What do you mean with "clips"? Also why did you added quotes around the 2nd and 3rd args in your comment?

Comment: translator said clips for quotes sorry. I need the result like in my question with quites  around each values

Comment: at the moment i get it only without quotes just the vaklue  with a comma then next value i. But i need around them quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
fwrite($file, '$tier['latitude']'.','.'$tier['longitude']');
```

This one is not correct, because you are opening simple-quote (') but you are closing it after `$tier[` and you are not concatenating `latitude`, PHP thinks `latitude` is a variable and you are not using dot (.) to concatenate it. See in my example the difference in colors, the same is PHP interpreting, thats why is giving you error.

Try this one

```php
fwrite($file, "'".$tier['latitude']."', '".$tier['longitude']."'\r\n");
```

Do you see the difference ? Let me know if it's working for you but you need other output.

Comment: Thx for helping out , i tried some similar but not exact this.
Its  that what i needed =) thank you all for your time to understand the question

Comment: @Artworkz you are welcome, remember that if you try to output a variable between simple-quote `'` you are going to literally output the variable name, you must use double-quote `"` if you want to output the variable content